# How to show all product tags in a single page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an e-book store  , how to show list of all product tags on page, If i use the following colde

```
<?php get_tags($args);?>
```

It shows only post tags, not product-tags
,Thanks in advance i m new in worpdress

Comment: There's `get_tags` method inside `WC_Product` class: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1186

Comment: How can i call it on a page, where i want to display a full list